# Elastic search range not working for double indexed as long

Tags: elasticsearch, type-conversion

I have mapped a field as long, but the input data is decimal (`100.123`).

I've tried any `range` search and it doesn't work. I've verified and the data is in the proper index and I can find them if I search for missing/exists.

Range query:

```
"range": {
  "nr_val": {
   "from": 123,
   "to": 1234
  }
}
```

Is Elasticsearch just ignoring the values, treating them as strings in a range search ?

So in my situation, what can I do to make a range search `from:100, to:200` work for 100.123 other than a full dump and re-import? Are there any conversion options available?

## Update with detailed specs

```
{
    "state": "open",
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1447858537098",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "uuid": "iiPzQXasQadvnDF1da8oMw",
            "version": {
                "created": "1070299"
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "mongo_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "parent": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "data.current.specs.nr._nrm_val": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "data.current.specs.nr_b._nrm_val": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "data": {
                    "properties": {
                        "current": {
                            "properties": {
                                "specs": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "nr": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "_nrm_val": {
                                                    "type": "double"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "nr_b": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "_nrm_val": {
                                                    "type": "long"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aliases": []
}
```

Seems that the mapping is not quite right... switched to `['data']['properties']['current']['properties'](...)` notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case that field should have been `double`, not `long`. And the indexed value for `100.123` is `100` and you loose the decimals.

At this point, other than re-indexing which is ideal, probably just scripted filtering will do it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "_source['nr'].value >= param1 && _source['nr'].value <= param2",
          "params": {
            "param1": 100,
            "param2": 200
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it will be expensive because of the `_source` loading.

Comment: The indexed value for 100.123 is 100 if I mark it as `double` ? What is the value now when it's long ?

Comment: The other way around: as `long` the indexed value is `100`. As `double` is the correct decimal one.

Comment: So why isn't the range search working? I have no problem with losing the decimals. I've added the code sample to the question.

Comment: What document in the index are you expecting to match for `"range": {
  "nr_val": {
   "from": 123,
   "to": 1234
  }
}`?

Comment: it should match `123.1234` , `124.01`, `125.02` `126` ... `1233.1`

Comment: no it didn't work, thought that was the problem and changed to double and re-imported, some fields work fine, some just don't using the same query, and checked and rechecked to see if they where added properly, even checked the index meta and it's `double` now

Comment: I've tried the script that you sent but I get an error: ` nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled`

Comment: also if I search for `gt:0` all fields with value in the database are displayed , if I set `gt:0.1` or `gt:1` no results

Comment: Inline scripting needs to be enabled in your elasticsearch.yml, how you do that depends on the version of ES you are running.

Comment: Let's get more specific: exactly what query doesn't work (leave the script one aside)? Provide the mapping of that field, as well. We need to make sure it's actually `double`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan you were right, the mapping wasn't done right, used `["data.field"] = ["type"=>"double"]` instead of `["data"]["properties"]["field"] = ["type"=>"double"]`